# how to make a nested data array in python

Tags: python

i have a nested data in array javascript,i want to make that in python,
what i should use to make multiple data inside an array like this in python.

```
const people = [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'Udin', age: 12 }, 
    { id: 2, name: 'Wati', age: 51 }, 
    { id: 3, name: 'Budi', age: 34 }, 
    { id: 4, name: 'Agus', age: 16 }, 
    { id: 5, name: 'Sari', age: 19 }, 
    { id: 6, name: 'Ririn', age: 21 }, 
]
```

Comment: like in the official JSON spec, you just need to quote the keys of each object.  you also can drop the `const` keyword.  Otherwise you're basically there already.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward, just have to quote the string keys:

```
people = [ 
    { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Udin', 'age': 12 }, 
    { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Wati', 'age': 51 }, 
    { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Budi', 'age': 34 }, 
    { 'id': 4, 'name': 'Agus', 'age': 16 }, 
    { 'id': 5, 'name': 'Sari', 'age': 19 }, 
    { 'id': 6, 'name': 'Ririn', 'age': 21 }, 
]
```